# Using a nested loop in R alternative

Tags: r, nested-loops, lapply, sapply

I have the following code that in R that I'm trying to speed up since I know loops are slower in R. Is there a way to do this R without having to use nested loops.

```
# initialize 2 vectors of length 10,000
totalNum <- rep(0,10000)
totalAmt <- rep(0,10000) 
values <- sample(200:5000,150000, replace = TRUE)
chances <-  # similar to f in length and contains values between 0 and 1 

# loop over length of a vector 
 for (i in 1:150000){
   # value between 200-5000 
   value <- values[i]
   # value of number between 0 and 1 
   chance <- chances[i]

  # loop over vectors created 
  for (j in 1:10000){
    # run test 
    dice <- runif(1)
    if (dice < chance){

    totalnum[j] <-  totalNum[j] + 1
    totalAmt[j] <- totalAmt[j] + value
   }

  }

}
```

I've been trying to use lapply or mapply but doesn't seem like it will work for this situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lapply` and `mapply` are just hidden loops with marginal improvement over a `for` loop.  For significant improvement you need to use the vectorized forms of the functions.

The inner loop is easily replaced with a vectorized form:

```
#generate all of the rolls
dice<-runif(10000)

#identify the affected index
dicelesschance<-which(dice<chance)

#update the values 
totalNum[dicelesschance]<-totalNum[dicelesschance] + 1
totalAmt[dicelesschance]<-totalAmt[dicelesschance] + value
```

This should have a noticeable improvement on performance.

Comment: Thank you man this really improved the speed from upwards of 30minutes to less than 2!!!!

Comment: @Onyambu, The logic here is to create a vector of 10000 dice rolls (the inner loop performs a new roll) and compare it to the chance value (which changes only on outer loop iteration), thus I believe the same logic as the original double loop.

Answer (score 2):

`size = 150000` for values and chances vectors

```
library('data.table')
df1 <- data.table(totalNum = rep(0,10000),
                  totalAmt = rep(0,10000))
values <- sample(200:5000,150000, replace = TRUE)
chances <-  runif(n=150000, min=1e-12, max=.9999999999)

invisible( mapply( function(value, chance){
  df1[runif(10000) < chance, `:=` (totalNum = totalNum + 1, totalAmt = totalAmt + value)]
  return(0)
}, value = values, chance = chances) )
```

On my system, this code completes with the following time using the `system.time()` function.

```
# user  system elapsed 
# 252.83   43.93  298.68
```